# Triggering a script when new TCP connection is established

Tags: networking, scripting, monitoring

So I need to run a script whenever a new TCP connection is established. I found the BCC - Tools tcpconnect.py to monitor the TCP connections but I can't find a way to leverage that tool to trigger my script.

Any ideas? This would be for a Debian Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `net-o-matic`.

I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.